# Any way to remove the grey background from ImageButtons?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an ImageButton and I'd like to remove the ugly (IMHO) background that surrounds the Image. I could just add an ImageView, but they're very hard to get set perfectly in a Layout like the grey one pictured. [gravity "Center" doesn't make it go to the middle, just centers it Vertically.)

So any way to remove that?

[image]

Comment: How did you add image to image button? android:src or android:background

Comment: I just dragged it into the Graphic Editor and [this](http://i.imgur.com/d2VTW.png) came up, letting me choose my picture. But every ImageButton has that gray gradient background around it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just use `android:background="#0000"` 
(#0000 same with #00000000)
or

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated as of API 16: Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean). Use `setBackground` instead

Comment: `setBackground(null)`

Answer (score 30):

The default background is not transparent.

So, just add the transparent color "#00000000" as you background, then you could solve it.

p.s. #00000000 is the transparent color

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon" 
android:background="#00000000"
/>
```

Comment: Google/ Android Should really tell you the Default Background is not Transparent, saves an hour looking on google and stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same problem but now it has been solved. If you are using `"android:background="@null"` it will resulted of no background at all and no button pressed animation will be appeared to the user.

Just adding this line of code to make an image button become flashing upon clicked. This is the proper way to alert the user an image button has been clicked.

```
 "android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can keep the square box and just change its color like this:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

works beautifully

Answer (score 3):

just use`android:background="@null"` in your xml

Comment: Cheers that really helped!

Answer (score 1):

All proposed solutions remove the ripple animation (on tap)

Settings background tint mode to 'add' will remove the background and keep ripple animation:

```
android:backgroundTintMode="add"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set the

```
android:background
```

instead of

```
android:src
```

it should overwrite the gray background

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. If you drag ImageButton that will usually ask for ImageSource. But the ImageSource(android:src) doesn't remove the gray background. It is an image that should be on top of background:

Instead of that try android:background in layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

please use the Draw 9-patch format for the image b'use it is provided by SDK

```
1. From a terminal, launch the draw9patch application from your SDK /tools directory.
2. Drag your PNG image into the Draw 9-patch window (or File > Open 9-patch... to locate  the file). Your workspace will now open.
```

The left pane is your drawing area, in which you can edit the lines for the stretchable patches and content area. The right pane is the preview area, where you can preview your graphic when stretched.

```
3. Click within the 1-pixel perimeter to draw the lines that define the stretchable patches and (optional) content area. Right-click (or hold Shift and click, on Mac) to erase previously drawn lines.

4. When done, select File > Save 9-patch...
```

Your image will be saved with the .9.png file name.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"

android:src="@drawable/icon"
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Xamarin Forms it can be done like this in the xaml view. Set background to transparent.

```
<ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent"
```